# Construct an associative array from 2 other arrays, and linked by a common key

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

**Problem:**

I would like to combine 2 associative arrays to make one. To link these arrays, the ID key is present in both.

**Input:**

To retrieve my contacts with api call, I have to do 2 requests : 
First to retrieve contacts with Id, and email adresse
Second to get some informations like name, city etc.

The first one return an array like this :

```
$contactArray = array(
    array(
        "CreatedAt" => "2019-04-12T11:53:26Z",
        "DeliveredCount" => 0,
        "Email" => "terry@example.org",
        "ExclusionFromCampaignsUpdatedAt" => "2019-04-28T09:21:35Z",
        "ID" => 1864410583,
        "IsExcludedFromCampaigns" => false,
        "IsOptInPending" => false,
        "IsSpamComplaining" => false,
        "LastActivityAt" => "2019-04-28T09:21:35Z",
        "LastUpdateAt" => "2019-04-28T09:21:35Z",
        "Name" => "",
        "UnsubscribedAt" => "",
        "UnsubscribedBy" => ""
    ),
    array(
        "CreatedAt" => "2019-04-12T12:39:30Z",
        "DeliveredCount" => 0,
        "Email" => "duane@example.org",
        "ExclusionFromCampaignsUpdatedAt" => "",
        "ID" => 1864410588,
        "IsExcludedFromCampaigns" => false,
        "IsOptInPending" => false,
        "IsSpamComplaining" => false,
        "LastActivityAt" => "2019-04-12T12:39:30Z",
        "LastUpdateAt" => "2019-04-12T12:39:30Z",
        "Name" => "",
        "UnsubscribedAt" => "",
        "UnsubscribedBy" => ""
    )
);
```

The second call, return an array like

```
$contactDataArray =
        array(
            array(
                "ContactID" => 1864410583,
                "Data" => array(
                    array(
                        "Name" => "firstname",
                        "Value" => "Mark"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Name" => "city",
                        "Value" => "Miami"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Name" => "name",
                        "Value" => "Terry"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Name" => "phone",
                        "Value" => "555-5555"
                    )
                ),
                "ID" => 1864410583
            ),
            array(
                "ContactID" => 1864410588,
                "Data" => array(
                    array(
                        "Name" => "firstname",
                        "Value" => "Jane"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Name" => "city",
                        "Value" => "New York"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Name" => "name",
                        "Value" => "Duane"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "Name" => "phone",
                        "Value" => "555-5555"
                    )
                ),
                "ID" => 1864410588
            )
        );
```

In `$contactArray`, the ID key matches with ContactID key and ID key in `$contactDataArray`

**Attempt:**
I want an array formatted like this :

```
$output = array(
        array(
            "Email" => "terry@example.org",
            "ID" => 1864410583,
            "firstname" => "Mark",
            "city" => "Miami",
            "name" => "Terry",
            "phone" => "555-5555"
        ),
        array(
            "Email" => "duane@example.org",
            "ID" => 1864410588,
            "firstname" => "Jane",
            "city" => "New York",
            "name" => "Duane",
            "phone" => "555-5555"
        )
    );
```

I'm trying to achieve this with array_walk, but no succeed.

Comment: Can you post your current attempt with `array_walk` and what is the problem with it? (any error, unexpected result, etc)

Comment: Why do you need the first array? seem all the data you want in the second array? And attemp mean share the code you tried... Did you try simple `foreach` loop?

Comment: @dWinder second array doesn't have email address

Comment: Oh, so user the id as key in the first array and then loop and the second one and add it - no need `array_walk`

Comment: I want to extract email and id of first array to put in the new array with others keys. And others keys transformed with value to key eg value name become the key of the value subarray

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with foreach,

```
$result = [];
foreach ($contactDataArray as $key => $value) {
    $ids   = array_column($contactArray, "ID"); // fetching all values from contactArray
    if (!empty(array_intersect([$value['ContactID'], $value['ID']], $ids))) { // checking if both satisfy the condition
        $result[$key] = array_column($value['Data'], 'Value', 'Name'); // combining name and value
        // searchng for key with matched ContactID
        $result[$key]['Email'] = $contactArray[array_search($value["ContactID"], $ids)]['Email'];
        $result[$key]['ID'] = $value["ContactID"];
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0add823d0d6949d79fd715c926f00be27748fb9c).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this?

```
$output = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($contactDataArray); $i++) {
    $arrIDandEmail = [
        'Email' => isset($contactArray[$i]['Email']) ? $contactArray[$i]['Email'] : '', 
        'ID' => isset($contactDataArray[$i]['ID']) ? $contactDataArray[$i]['ID'] : ''
    ];
    $arrData = array_column($contactDataArray[$i]["Data"], "Value", "Name");
    $newArray = array_merge($arrIDandEmail, $arrData);
    $output[] = $newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP >= 7.1 you can use array destructuring using [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
<?php 

$output = [];

foreach ($contactDataArray as [
    'ID' => $id,
    'Data' => [
        ['Name' => $firstnameKey, 'Value' => $firstnameValue],
        ['Name' => $cityKey, 'Value' => $cityValue],
        ['Name' => $nameKey, 'Value' => $nameValue],
        ['Name' => $phoneKey, 'Value' => $phoneValue]
    ]
]) {
    $output[] = [
        "Email" => $contactArray[array_search($id, array_column($contactArray, 'ID'))]['Email'],
        "ID" => $id,
        $firstnameKey => $firstnameValue,
        $cityKey => $cityValue,
        $nameKey => $nameValue,
        $phoneKey => $phoneValue
    ];
}

var_dump($output);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9Ghhb)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk`,`array_combine`,`array_column` for the desired array as a result

```
$res = [];
array_walk($contactArray, function($v, $k) use ($contactDataArray,&$res)
{
  $res[] = array_merge(['Email'=>$v['Email'],'ID'=>$v['ID']],
            array_combine(
                array_column($contactDataArray[$k]['Data'],'Name'),
                array_column($contactDataArray[$k]['Data'],'Value')
            )
   );
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b892b73261162e98a41e64581b9b621df1087e2)